# Given a SQLAlchemy query object how can I determine if and how it has been ordered?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Assume `Post` is SQLAlchemy model, if I have SQLAlchemy queries like:

```
query1 = Post.query.filter_by(category_id=2)
query2 = Post.query.filter_by(category_id=2).order_by(Post.id.desc())
query3 = Post.query.filter_by(category_id=2).order_by(Post.foobar)
```

How can I programmatically determine which column (e.g., `None`, `Post.id`, and `Post.foobar`) the queries are ordered by?

Comment: There is a `queryN._order_by_clauses` attribute which looks like it might provide what you want via each elements `base_columns` attribute for `query3`.  For `query2`, the element is a `UnaryExpression` instance - I'm not sure how you would get back to `id.desc()` from that.

Comment: Another alternative might be to use `sql = str(queryN.compile())` to generate the SQL statement and then look for an ORDER BY clause inside it.